# How to autosuggest for entries that may already exist using title in the add entry form using typeahead and CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, autocomplete, cakephp-3.0, typeahead.js

If you notice when typing the title of a question in StackOverflow, SO will attempt to suggest questions that already contain the answer. Right below the title itself.

For e.g.

[image]

I am trying to do something similar in CakePHP 3.1 for a model called Companies.

For `Companies`,

I want to auto-suggest possible existing companies based on the name field right below the name as well.

See the form below

[image]

If you notice, there are 4 words supplied. `Wuhan`, `Electric`, `Co`, `Ltd`

I want to fetch a list of possible existing companies which have names containing at least one of the words `Wuhan`, `Electric`.

In terms of MySQL query, it will be something like

```
SELECT id, name from companies where name 
WHERE MATCH (name)
AGAINST ('Wuhan Eletric Co Ltd' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

In my mind, I need the following:

1. a way to implement the autocomplete
2. an endpoint for the ajax to collect a list of possible companies

For 1, my googling led me to find typeahead.js http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

My questions for typeahead.js are:

a) can I separate the display of the fetched results separate from the text input of the name field?

b) which type of typeahead should I use? Options include remote dataset, custom templates, etc.

c) should I even use typeahead.js? Should I use something else instead?

For 2, my questions are

a) since I am using crud from https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud, is there a standard action I can use?

b) or I need to change the conditions?

What I am using:

- CakePHP 3.1.1
- Crud 4.2.0

**Why do I need this?**

I want to prevent users accidentally duplicate companies while at the same time, I cannot set it such that the name of the company is a unique field in the database.

Comment: "In terms of MySQL query, it will be something like ```

SELECT id, name from companies where name like '%Wuhan%' or name like  '%Electric% ```. "  No you need fulltext search condition.

Comment: Thanks man. I changed the query as you suggested